# Simplifying code, avoiding copy and paste

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I started building Swift apps for about 8 months and one of them has a very big structure with many `viewControllers` and `tableViews` along with `navbars` in each one of them.

After months of experience, I discovered other ways to simplify things to achieve a cleaner code through `Protocols`, `container views`, etc.

The project has 17 `viewControllers` where I copied and pasted most of the`tableViews` with its `UITableViewDelegate` and `DataSource` from a common file in the `Resources` folder. `navbars` and all the code with its functionality are also the same in every `viewController`, having the same code repeated over and over again.

Is there a way I could implement all the `IBOutlets` for every `navbar` and all the functions for each `UITableViewDelegate` without having to write the same code in every `viewController`?

My guess is to maybe create an extension and global variables or a singleton for the `tableView`.. but what about the `navbars`?

Comment: Impossible to answer without having a look at your project... and the answer would be opinion-based anyway.

Comment: @Christian, you should provide more information, and at least show us your `storyboard`, and the directory structure of your project.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the question as it is primarily opinion based.

Comment: Why are the navbars in code instead of storyboards? Please show an example of navbar code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you can just create a base view controller with all shared functionality and layout and all view controllers that make use of the same table view and nav bar could inherit from this base view controller.

Comment: Thanks, I tried what you suggested and it works. The only problem is that  when I tried adding a new `tableView` inheriting from the `baseViewController`, it won't let me, as I am using an `extension` for `UITableViewDelegate` with this `baseViewController`. But it's no big deal, just trying to squeeze my code.